# ko.bindingHandlers.datepicker not working for knockout version 3.0

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, datepicker, knockout-2.0, knockout-3.0

Currently i am using knockout 2.1.0 where following datepicker binding working perfectly for non observable value.When i have updated knockout 3.0 it is not working

```
ko.bindingHandlers.datepicker = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
        // Get the options from the binding.
        var options = allBindingsAccessor().datepickerOptions || {};

        $(element)
      .datepicker(options)
      .bind("change", function() {
          ko.bindingHandlers.datepicker.updateValue(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor);
      });

        ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function() {
            $(element).datepicker("destroy");
        });
    },
    update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
        var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());

        // If the date is coming from a Microsoft webservice.
        if (typeof value === "string" && value.indexOf('/Date(') === 0) {
            value = new Date(parseInt(value.replace(/\/Date\((.*?)\)\//gi, "$1")));
        }
        var currentDate = $(element).datepicker("getDate");

        // Check if the date has changed.
        if (value && value - currentDate !== 0) {
            $(element).datepicker("setDate", value);
        }
    },
    updateValue: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
        var observable = valueAccessor(),
        dateValue = $(element).datepicker("getDate");

        // Two-way-binding means a writeable observable.
        if (ko.isWriteableObservable(observable)) {
            observable(dateValue);
            return;
        }
        if (allBindingsAccessor()._ko_property_writers) {
            allBindingsAccessor()._ko_property_writers.datepicker(dateValue);
        }
    }
};
```

When i debug the code i came to know that  is `allBindingsAccessor()._ko_property_writers` is undefined .because of which i am not able to update the nonobservable value.

[JsFIddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p9B4w/16/)

Can anybody suggest me the solution for above code in 3.0 version

By using below example i have modified the my custom binding and it is working great .Please find the Updated fiddle

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p9B4w/19/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `_ko_property_writers` is a private implementation detail (which is why the name is prefix with `_`). If you read [line 188-195 in the source code for expression rewriting in knockout](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/blob/master/src/binding/expressionRewriting.js#L188-L195) you'll see that it states the following:

> Making bindings explicitly declare themselves as "two way" isn't ideal in the long term (it would be better if all bindings could use an official 'property writer' API without needing to declare that they might). However, since this is not, and has never been, a public API (_ko_property_writers was never documented), it's acceptable as an internal implementation detail in the short term.
>
> For those developers who rely on _ko_property_writers in their custom bindings, we expose _twoWayBindings as an undocumented feature that makes it relatively easy to upgrade to KO 3.0. However, this is still not an official public API, and we reserve the right to remove it at any time if we create a real public property writers API.

So it would seem like there is still not a public API which won't change to future versions, but you should be able to use `_twoWayBindings` until such an API is decided and provided.

*UPDATED 2014-04-15 - Adding a sample of setting the two way binding flag*

The `_twoWayBindings` setting (which might disappear in any future version of knockout, since it's not really a public API, unfortunately) is a flag you can set when you create your `bindingHandler` to tell knockout to create a `_ko_property_writers` entry for your `bindingHandler`. The way you set this flag is similar to how you create a new bindingHandler:

```
ko.expressionRewriting._twoWayBindings['simpleTwoWayBinding'] = true;
```

A complete example of a binding which would do two way binding to non-observable properties:

```
ko.expressionRewriting._twoWayBindings['simpleTwoWayBinding'] = true;
ko.bindingHandlers['simpleTwoWayBinding'] = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel){
        element.value = valueAccessor();
        var valueSetter = allBindings.get('_ko_property_writers').simpleTwoWayBinding;
        element.addEventListener('change', function(){
            valueSetter(element.value);
        });
    }
};
```

I have a working sample which you can find at http://jsfiddle.net/p8ugz/

However, do be aware that the above code will not work with observable properties. To support both, you need to check if it's bound to an observable and just work with ordinary observables in that case and with the `_ko_property_writers` if it's not an observable.

Comment: If you could please edit your question and add a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and describe the issues with the minimal example, I'll have a look and see if I can get the minimal example to work.

Comment: Yes, you had written a sample. However, your question was regarding a knockout specific thing and your fiddle has five external libraries. The example on jsfiddle shows off a lot more than just the minimum necessary; which would have been just creating a simple two-way binding with knockout. Also, your sample doesn't discuss what issues you were having after being informed of the `_twoWayBindings` flag. Nevertheless, I have updated my answer with a sample on setting the `_twoWayBindings` flag for a custom `bindingHandler`.

Comment: Thanks for the example Robert..I have modified the plugin .Now able to change the value of nonobservable..